# Retrieving data from geonames using SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, geonames

I am trying to get linked data from geonames in the following SPARQL, but obviously I'm doing someting wrong.

```
prefix oxprop: <http://ophileon.com/ox/property#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

select ?poi ?poiname ?geonames ?latitude


from  <http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf>
# from  <http://sws.geonames.org/ >

where
{

   ?poi rdfs:label ?poiname.
   ?poi owl:sameAs ?geonames.
#   ?geonames wgs84_pos:lat ?latitude.


  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?poiname), "EN")).

}
```

which, using sparql.org 's JSON output :

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "poi" , "poiname" , "geonames" , "latitude" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "poi": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/2" } ,
        "poiname": { "type": "literal" , "xml:lang": "en" , "value": "Wageningen" } ,
        "geonames": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://sws.geonames.org/2745088" }
      } ,
      {
        "poi": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/3" } ,
        "poiname": { "type": "literal" , "xml:lang": "en" , "value": "Netherlands" } ,
        "geonames": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://sws.geonames.org/2750405" }
      } ,
      {
        "poi": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/1" } ,
        "poiname": { "type": "literal" , "xml:lang": "en" , "value": "Amsterdam" } ,
        "geonames": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://sws.geonames.org/2759794" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that it retrieves the latitude of each node using the geonames rdf service with addresses like "http://sws.geonames.org/2745088/about.rdf"

The lines starting with "#" are the ones I suspect to be incorrect..

Next iteration

After having added  "/" behind the geonamesID , and running this:

```
prefix oxprop: <http://ophileon.com/ox/property#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

select *

from <http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf>
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2745088/about.rdf>    
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2750405/about.rdf>    
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2759794/about.rdf>
where
{
   ?poi rdfs:label ?poiname.
   ?poi owl:sameAs ?geonames.
   ?geonames wgs84_pos:lat ?latitude.
   FILTER(langMatches(lang(?poiname), "EN")).
}
```

Returns this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| poi                            | poiname          | geonames                           | latitude   |
=======================================================================================================
| <http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/2> | "Wageningen"@en  | <http://sws.geonames.org/2745088/> | "51.97"    |
| <http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/3> | "Netherlands"@en | <http://sws.geonames.org/2750405/> | "52.5"     |
| <http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/1> | "Amsterdam"@en   | <http://sws.geonames.org/2759794/> | "52.37403" |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Next iteration :  using   "SERVICE" keyword

```
prefix oxprop: <http://ophileon.com/ox/property#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>


select ?poi ?poiname ?geonameuri ?latitude

from <http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf>

where
{
   ?poi rdfs:label ?poiname.
   ?poi owl:sameAs ?geonameuri.
   SERVICE <http://factforge.net/sparql>{
   ?geonameuri wgs84_pos:lat ?latitude.
   }
   FILTER(langMatches(lang(?poiname), "EN")).
}
```

which results in what I wanted, except that factforge returns multiple values in various datatypes.
This resource http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/latc/www2012/Session%201.html proved to be very useful.

Comment: Where is the data? What endpoint are you running this query against?  You may want to consider using the `service` keyword, if you need to get triples from different endpoints.

Comment: I'm running it using spargl.org 's generic endpoint at http://sparql.org/sparql.html .  I've also done trials with various graphs, just repeating the FROM clause. As long as they are withing the ophileon.com domain and they are just rdf files ther's no problem. The data is partially in the rdf on my server, and partially somewhere in the geonames domain.

Comment: Do you actually have a space in the IRI in `from  <http://sws.geonames.org/ >`?  That would be a problem.  Also, please show the error message for when things _don't_ work.  When I use your query with those lines uncommented (but with the space in the IRI),  I get a parse error.  When I remove the space, I get a descriptive error "Failed to determine the triples content type: (URI=http://sws.geonames.org/ : stream=null : hint=null)", which means that Jena tried to retrieve the data, but couldn't figure out how to parse it.

Comment: Did you change the data on your server that the this query is retrieving?  In the results I got when I started looking into this, I got results for `geonames` like `<http://sws.geonames.org/2745088>` there there is _no_ final `/` on the URI, but now when I run the query, there is a final `/`.  I could see this being the problem, but I can't explain why it seems to have changed, except that your data on the server changed.

Comment: Yes I did, and I stated it in my edit ;)   I added the slash in the poi.rdf

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : SERVICE keyword proved to do the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you think you could post your query as an answer?  It will be more fitting answer than mine (since it will certainly be the one that fit you best), and it will be more useful to someone in the same situation in the future.  It's quite alright to unaccept an answer when a better one comes along, so you can accept your own answer, too.  I'm interested to know how you got `service` to work here.

Comment: Ah, I bet it's related to the query in your [newer question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19412208/1281433).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Typos and Inability to Retrieve Data

I think there are two issues here.  The first is a minor typo.  When I run your query, with the commented lines uncommented, I get a parse error because of the line

```
from  <http://sws.geonames.org/ >
```

because there should not be a space in the IRI.  That's easy to fix though.  When fixed, the service at sparql.org replies that

```
Error 400: Failed to load URL (parse error) http://sws.geonames.org/ : Failed to determine the triples content type: (URI=http://sws.geonames.org/ : stream=null : hint=null)

Fuseki - version 1.0.0 (Build date: 2013-09-12T10:49:49+0100)
```

which, I believe, means that Jena was able to pull down the content of that IRI, but wasn't able to figure out how to read it as RDF.   While a quick Google search shows plenty of queries where that IRI is used as a namespace prefix, I don't see any where it's used as a graph from which triples can be selected.  I think this matches what geonames.org says in its [documentation](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html):

> #### Entry Points into the GeoNames Semantic Web
>
> There are several ways how you can enter the GeoNames Semantic Web :
>
> - start from [mother earth](http://sws.geonames.org/6295630/) and follow the Linked Data links.
> - use the [geonames search webservice](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) with the *type=rdf* parameter option.
> - download the database dump and construct the url for the features
>     using the pattern "http://sws.geonames.org/geonameId/"
> - [RDF dump](http://download.geonames.org/all-geonames-rdf.zip) with
>     8514201 features and about 125 mio rdf triples (2013 08 27). The dump
>     has one rdf document per toponym on every line of the file. Note: The
>     file is pretty large. Make sure the tool you use to uncompress is able
>     to deal with the size and does not stop after 2GB, an issue that
>     happens with some old (windows) tool versions.

I'm a bit surprised to *not* see a SPARQL endpoint in that list, but I expect that if there was one, it would be in this list of options.

### Modifying the query to get some data

Now, the successful query (without the commented lines) returns these results:

```
poi                            poiname          geonames                          latitude
<http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/2> "Wageningen"@en  <http://sws.geonames.org/2745088>   
<http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/3> "Netherlands"@en <http://sws.geonames.org/2750405>   
<http://ophileon.com/ox/poi/1> "Amsterdam"@en   <http://sws.geonames.org/2759794>
```

**Note: These were the results at the time that I started writing this answer.  However, this is based on data in `http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf`, which may have changed.  On later runs of this query, I get values of `geonames` that have a final `/`, e.g., `http://sws.geonames.org/2745088/`.**

Based on the same documentation, which also says that:

> For the town Embrun in France we have these two URIs:
>
> 1. http://sws.geonames.org/3020251/
> 2. http://sws.geonames.org/3020251/about.rdf
>
> The first URI [1] stands for
>   the town in France. You use this URI if you want to refer to the town.
>   The second URI [2] is the document with the information geonames has
>   about Embrun.

This suggests that a query with those particular geonames IRIs also used as graphs names might work.  That is, that a query like this might work:

```
prefix oxprop: <http://ophileon.com/ox/property#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

select ?poi ?poiname ?geonames ?latitude
from <http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf>
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2745088/about.rdf>    
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2750405/about.rdf>    
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2759794/about.rdf>
where
{
   ?poi rdfs:label ?poiname.
   ?poi owl:sameAs ?geonames.
   ?geonames wgs84_pos:lat ?latitude.
   FILTER(langMatches(lang(?poiname), "EN")).
}
```

Now this *still* doesn't return any results, but it seems like all the data should be there. Let's try a simpler query.  If you use a query like this:

```
select * 
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2759794/about.rdf>
where { ?s ?p ?o }
```

[SPARQL results](http://sparql.org/sparql?query=select%20%2a%20%0D%0Afrom%20%3Chttp://sws.geonames.org/2759794/about.rdf%3E%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%20?s%20?p%20?o%20%7D&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=/xml-to-html.xsl)

you'll get a bunch of triples about that place.  This does work with multiple `from` clauses, too.  For instance, if you use that data and your data with the following query, you get the combined results.

```
select * 
from <http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf>
from <http://sws.geonames.org/2745088/about.rdf>  
where { ?s ?p ?o }
```

[SPARQL results](http://sparql.org/sparql?query=select%20%2a%20%0D%0Afrom%20%3Chttp://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf%3E%0D%0Afrom%20%3Chttp://sws.geonames.org/2745088/about.rdf%3E%20%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%20?s%20?p%20?o%20%7D&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=/xml-to-html.xsl)

In looking at the results from that dataset, we can finally see where the problem is:  the IRIs for the geonames resources end with `/` in their actual form, but don't have `/` in your data.  You'll need to change your data accordingly.

**Note: it seems that the data in `http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf` has since been corrected.**

It looks like you may end up needing to run your first query to determine data you want to get from geonames, retrieving that information, and then running a second query on that.  Alternatively, you could download the big data dump provided by Geonames and use it locally (possibly the easiest solution).

Comment: Joshua, thanks for your elaborate answer. I've been able to get a little step closer , by adding a "/" after the geonamesID's in http://www.ophileon.com/ox/poi.rdf.

Comment: @Ophileon Yes, I realized this morning that that was one of the problems.  In the future (and I should have thought of this earlier), could you provide your data in a way where is won't change behind the scenes?  Some the results I mentioned above are now invalid because the off-site data (i.e., the data that's not on Stack Overflow) has been modified.

Comment: @Ophileon If only SPARQL 1.1 supported `from` clauses in nested queries, you could even generate the URIs that you need for the `from` clauses dynamically, and do this all in one query.   As it is now though, it looks like you'll either need to download the data and use it locally, or run one query to figure out what other URIs you need, and then use a second query that incorporates those with `from` clauses.

Comment: that is also my conclusion. not happy with it, but there seems not be a better solution.