# How do I get a place (city, province, country) information from Geonames having the place's name using JENA and SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, geonames, opendata

Could someone help me with a SPARQL query to Geonames database to find a place's information, i.e., population? I have just the place's name. I am using JENA.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code factory, and there are lots of questions about running SPARQL queries with Jena, and even (I think) some about Geonames.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: E.g., does [Retrieving data from geonames using SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19393908/1281433) help?

Comment: that is a good question @JoshuaTaylor asked! Give us some info as in what have you tried that failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the Geonames Java Library (see http://www.geonames.org/source-code/). Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
//First, must be registered on Geonames. Then, place the user here...
WebService.setUserName("demo");

ToponymSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ToponymSearchCriteria();
searchCriteria.setQ("My City Name");
searchCriteria.setStyle(Style.FULL);
ToponymSearchResult searchResult;
Long population;

try {
    searchResult = WebService.search(searchCriteria);
    for (Toponym toponym : searchResult.getToponyms()) {
    population = toponym.getPopulation();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {     
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return population;
```